# Why I get different size on pandas dataframe after append or concat?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

candle_data = pd.DataFrame()

for fileName in files:
    csv_data = pd.read_csv(fileName, header=None)
    candle_data = pd.concat([candle_data, csv_data])
    #candle_data = candle_data.append(csv_data)  

print(candle_data)
print(candle_data.tail(3))
```

the result is:

```
                0      1        2        3        4        5  6
0      2000.05.30  17:27  0.93020  0.93020  0.93020  0.93020  0
1      2000.05.30  17:35  0.93040  0.93050  0.93040  0.93050  0
2      2000.05.30  17:38  0.93040  0.93040  0.93030  0.93030  0
...
29781  2016.04.29  16:55  1.14512  1.14524  1.14503  1.14515  0
29782  2016.04.29  16:56  1.14515  1.14517  1.14491  1.14495  0
29783  2016.04.29  16:57  1.14494  1.14505  1.14482  1.14482  0
29784  2016.04.29  16:58  1.14477  1.14511  1.14457  1.14457  0

[5171932 rows x 7 columns]
                0      1        2        3        4        5  6
29782  2016.04.29  16:56  1.14515  1.14517  1.14491  1.14495  0
29783  2016.04.29  16:57  1.14494  1.14505  1.14482  1.14482  0
29784  2016.04.29  16:58  1.14477  1.14511  1.14457  1.14457  0
```

Why did I get 5171932x7 as the dimension while printing the whole dataframe, but 29784 as the last row index?
What is the correct way to merge all rows of two dataframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are `duplicates` in `index`:

You can add parameter `ignore_index=True` to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) if don't have a meaningful index:

```
pd.concat([candle_data, csv_data], ignore_index=True)
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#ignoring-indexes-on-the-concatenation-axis)

Comment: Super, glad can help you! Good luck!